# How can i check if the Object' typeSoftware has (-1) value and remove it from it?

Tags: javascript, angular, string

I have this object and type software is his property, I have -1  in some cases. I want to remove it from the object before I go to the server

> Object companyName: "dsfdsfdsfsd" companyVatId: "dsfdsfdsf"
>   companyWebsite: "dfdsfsdf" country: "DZ" email: "sdfsdfs@gmail.com"
>   firstName: "sdfsdf" lastName: "fsdfs" other: "dsfsdf" phone:
>   "sdfsdfsdfsf" positionInTheCompany: "dfsdfsd" productDescription:
>   "dsfsdfsdf" productName: "sdfdsfdsf" typeSoftware: "2, -1"

The result should be for this case :

> Object companyName: "dsfdsfdsfsd" companyVatId: "dsfdsfdsf"
>   companyWebsite: "dfdsfsdf" country: "DZ" email: "sdfsdfs@gmail.com"
>   firstName: "sdfsdf" lastName: "fsdfs" other: "dsfsdf" phone:
>   "sdfsdfsdfsf" positionInTheCompany: "dfsdfsd" productDescription:
>   "dsfsdfsdf" productName: "sdfdsfdsf" typeSoftware: "2"

Comment: Why dont you just check if you have -1 in typeSoftware property and if you do remove last two chars. "2, -1" is type of string?

Comment: I just need to remove -1

Comment: @Aleksandra is it in object ( proper JS object format ) or  `stringified JS object` or the same string format you given in question ?

Comment: With no further information it's as simple as `Object.typeSoftware = Object.typeSoftware.replace(", -1", "");`  Where do you get this data, is it an object or a string?  Please create a **[mcve]** to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @CodeManiac is the same as its in question format

Comment: it looks like you could remove `-1` before doing `join(', ')`

Comment: @Kos how? can this be done

Comment: @Aleksandra, `.join(', ')` joins an array into a string, `.filter(v => v != '-1').join(', ')` will filter out values that equal `'-1'` and then will join the resulting array into a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use replace an capturing group

```
\btypeSoftware:\s*"([^"]+)"
```

With this pattern we capture `typeSoftware: " followed by  value "`

In call back of replace function we take the captured group and split it on `,` and than we filter out the desired value and join them `,`

```js
let str = `Object companyName: "dsfdsfdsfsd" companyVatId: "dsfdsfdsf" companyWebsite: "dfdsfsdf" country: "DZ" email: "sdfsdfs@gmail.com" firstName: "sdfsdf" lastName: "fsdfs" other: "dsfsdf" phone: "sdfsdfsdfsf" positionInTheCompany: "dfsdfsd" productDescription: "dsfsdfsdf" productName: "sdfdsfdsf" typeSoftware: "2, -1" `

let final = (str) =>str.replace(/\btypeSoftware:\s*"([^"]+)"/g, (match,g1)=>{
  return `typeSoftware:"${g1.split(',').filter(e=> e.trim() !== '-1' && e).join(',')}"`
})

console.log(final(str))

// this will handle following case too

console.log(final(`typeSoftware:"-1, 2, 5, 9"`))
console.log(final(`typeSoftware:"2, -1, 4,"`))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with regex or arrays functions.
If your object is a string you have to call `JSON.parse(o)` first

```js
//o is your Object
o = {typeSoftware:  '2 , -1 ,6'}
o.typeSoftware = o.typeSoftware.split(',').map(x => x.trim()).filter(y => y !== '-1').join(', ');
console.log(o.typeSoftware)
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex will help you removing last standing `-1` or `, -1` in a string:

```js
'2, -1'.replace(/(,|^)\s*-1$/, '')
```

Heres an example:

```js
const typeSoftware = '-1';
const result = typeSoftware.replace(/(,|^)\s?-1$/, '');

console.log(typeSoftware);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: what if const typeSoftware = '2 , -1 ,6';, will it remove -1

Comment: @Aleksandra no, only a single last `-1` in the string

Comment: @Aleksandra use `/((,|^)\s*-1\s*(?=,|$))*/` to remove all `-1` entries, though it might leave handing commas `,`.